# Passing AWS S3 environment variables to docker with an R script

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, rstudio

I have a dataframe I would like to write to an S3 bucker. I am using [aws.s3](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3) for this task. My script looks like the following.

```
library(aws.s3)

# set up AWS credentials
Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = "ASUPERSECRETSTRING",
           "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "ASUPERSECRETSTRING",
           "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = "us-east-somwhere")

s3write_using(my_data, FUN = write.csv,
          bucket = "www.My_bucket",
          object = unique_name)
```

I don't have any problems with the above script, but I don't like hard coding my AWS credentials. What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: You can include them in your Rprofile.site instead by setting them at startup `Sys.setenv("envvar"="var")` then call them with `Sys.getenv("envvar")`. I've seen a lot of people run a script like this that they exclude from git using `.gitignore`. Alternatively, you can use your CI and add the environment variables there (if you use CI).

Comment: pass env to docker run and set env in your script.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen `Rprofile.site` makes a lot of sense. Is there a chance that you can provide a link for documentation on how to do this?

Comment: @Adiii using the example code above, how would I pass env to `docker run` and set env in the script.

Comment: @Alex i check this with some online editor. please let me know if this any issue

Comment: See: `?Rprofile.site`. I've also seen people use a small package with only an .onLoad() function that registers the env vars as soon as it's called with library/req

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass your ENV to docker run command

```
sudo docker run -dit -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='your_key' -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='your_secret' -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION='bucket_region' busybox sh
```

Then modify a bit your script.

```
  test_env=Sys.getenv(c("R_HOME"))
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=Sys.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID");
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=Sys.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=Sys.getenv("AWS_DEFAULT_REGION")
  message("test env is:",test_env)
```

Above code will get env and also one test env. If you still need to call Sys.setenv then you can pass like this once you get env.

```
Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
           "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
           "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
```

Comment: Don't use it if already override cmd in your Dockers file, it just example